# How to alert map() values after an <option> of a <select> tag has been selected using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was tasked to use a map to store the names of 5 students with their corresponding
average grade. I have initialised this map with fictitious hardcoded
names and grades as follows:

```
const avgGrade = new Map();

avgGrade.set('Kyle', '82%');
avgGrade.set('Sarah', '50%');
avgGrade.set('Skye', '96%');
avgGrade.set('Taylor', '75%');
avgGrade.set('Bantu', '98%');
```

My goal is to write the JavaScript to display the name of each student in a
drop-down menu. When the student’s name is selected from the
drop-down menu, the student’s grade should be displayed using an
alert.  These are the hints I was given (Hint: Remember that you can use the value and innerHTML
attributes of an  element.)

I tried doing this, but there is something I'm not getting right. can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong. Here's my code:

```
//dropdown menu using a for loop 

let dropdown = document.querySelector('#dropdown');
for (i=0; i<avgGrade.length; i++){
let option = document.createElement('option');
option.innerHTML = avgGrade.keys();
dropdown.appendChild(option);
}

//also,I to just alert like this:
function studentGrades()//called the function in select tag on the DOM using the onchange event
{
alert( Select.options[selectedIndex].value + ' average grade is ' + avgGrade.values[i]);
}
```

Comment: `i<avgGrade.length` - your `avgGrade` does not have a `length` property. Maps have `size` instead.

Comment: `option.innerHTML = avgGrade.keys();` makes no sense; The `keys` method will return you an _array_ of _all_ the keys.

Comment: Also you mean `dropdown.options` and not `Select.options`

Comment: in the `alert`, it should be `dropdown.options[selectedIndex]`. Also, `selectedIndex` and `i` are not defined in `studentGrades()`

Comment: Click [edit] then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to make sure you are iterating [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) correctly. You can use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) for that. To insert your `options` please give both `text` and `value`.

Variables like `Select` , `i`, `selectedIndex` are not defined in your code.

To get the values from `Map`, please use standard Map methods like  [`get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get).

```js
const avgGrade = new Map();

avgGrade.set('Kyle', '82%');
avgGrade.set('Sarah', '50%');
avgGrade.set('Skye', '96%');
avgGrade.set('Taylor', '75%');
avgGrade.set('Bantu', '98%');

let dropdown = document.querySelector('#dropdown');
avgGrade.forEach((val, key) => {
  let option = document.createElement('option');
  option.text = key;
  option.value = key;

  dropdown.appendChild(option);
});

//also,I to just alert like this:
function studentGrades(select) {
  //called the function in select tag on the DOM using the onchange event
  alert(select.value + ' average grade is ' + avgGrade.get(select.value));
}
```

```html
<select id="dropdown" onchange="studentGrades(this)">
</select>
```

I took the liberty of passing `this` as an argument on the onChange. You might be doing it some other way.